# Java Scanner Delimiters

Tags: delimiter

I am scanning a text file using Scanner and the next() method and adding each individual word to an ArrayList. How can I use delimiters to ignore punctuation? I have words such as:

cat,
dog.
"mouse

I want to remove the comma, period and quotation marks in these words respectively. How can I do this?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761501/remove-part-of-string-following-regex-match-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can split a string on a regex using the [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method, so you could pass a regex with all the punctuation you don't want to it, in the case you mentioned it would be

```
String[] words = "cat, dog. \" mouse".split("[\\\",\\.]");
```

Although in this case words would contain some empty values so to add it to your array you would need to do something like:

```
for (String word : words) {
    if(!word.isEmpty()) {
        arrayList.add(word);
    }
}
```